# Getting the terms with high document frequency

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get the top 10 terms with highest document frequencies?

I have an analyzed field called `article`.

I am using ES 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an aggregation:

```
POST /my_articles/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "term_count":{
            "terms": {
                "field":"article",
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For each word, it will return the number of document where it can be found. But it doesn't take into account if a word is here multiple times in the field.